# How to get all PDF links from HTML content using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve all PDF links from a string column which contains HTML.

Example text of one column is:

```html
<p>text here <a href="example.com/abc.pdf">link</a>
 some other text <a href="example.com">home</a>
 <a href="www.example.com/abc123.pdf">link 2</a></p>
```

I need all links with .pdf extension.

I already tried function like this

```sql
ALTER function [dbo].[GetLinks] (@t nvarchar(max))
    returns @Links table (link nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    declare @strtpos int
    set @strtpos=100
    declare @endpos int 
    declare @lnk nvarchar(max)
    while @strtpos > 6
    begin
        set @strtpos = PATINDEX('%href="%', @t)+6
        if @strtpos>6 begin
            --set @endpos = CHARINDEX ('"',@t,@strtpos+1)
            set @endpos = PATINDEX('%.pdf"%',@t)+4
            if @endpos>0 begin
                set @lnk = substring(@t ,@strtpos, @endpos - @strtpos)
                set @strtpos = PATINDEX('%href="%', @lnk)+6
                set @t= RIGHT (@t, len(@t) - @endpos)

                insert @Links values(@lnk)
            end
        end
    end 

    return
end
```

And calling this function from SQL Server like this:

```sql
select top 1 * from dbo.GetLinks(' <p>text here <a href="example.com/abc.pdf">link</a>
     some other text <a href="example.com">home</a>
     <a href="www.example.com/abc123.pdf">link 2</a></p>')
```

This returns the first link only when I match CHAR, but when I match string ".pdf" it returns long string. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or need to change approach for this.

Comment: I suggest doing this in a different language. T-SQL's string manipulation capabilities is not it's strong point.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xquery expression can do it simply

```
DECLARE @html xml = '<p>text here <a href="example.com/abc.pdf">link<b v="3">ok</b></a>some other text <a href="example.com">home</a><a title="er">kj</a><a href="www.example.com/abc123.pdf">link 2</a></p>'

select [pdfLink] = a.value('@href','varchar(max)')
from @html.nodes('//a[@href[contains(., ".pdf")]]') c(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your html column can be converted to XML like your example suggests, your can parse the href values in T-SQL using XML data type methods:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLinks (@t xml)
    RETURNS @Links TABLE (link nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT @Links 
    SELECT
        AnchorTag.value('@href', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS link
    FROM @t.nodes('//a') AS AnchorTags(AnchorTag);

RETURN;
END;
GO
```

The same approach can be used with an inline TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLinks (@t xml)
    RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT
        AnchorTag.value('@href', 'nvarchar(MAX)') AS link
    FROM @t.nodes('//a') AS AnchorTags(AnchorTag)
);
GO
```

Comment: Probably wise to actually filter the nodes `//a[@h != ""]]`. Or perhaps even just the PDFs with `//a[@h[substring(., string-length(3), 1) = "pdf"]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2016+ you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = '
<p>text here <a href="example.com/abc.pdf">link</a>
 some other text <a href="example.com">home</a>
 <a href="www.example.com/abc123.pdf">link 2</a></p>';

SELECT TheUrl = split.value
FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@string,'"') AS split
WHERE  split.value LIKE '%.pdf';
```

**Returns:**

```
TheUrl
---------------------------
example.com/abc.pdf
www.example.com/abc123.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't convert your html into xml for whatever reason, you can still do this with regular string manipluation, though it is not pretty.

This solution (ironically) utilises an xml based string splitter to allow for multi-character delimiters, the output of which is then further filtered to only return the `.pdf` links:

```
create or alter function [dbo].[fn_StringSplitXML]
(
    @str       varchar(max) = ''    -- String to split.
   ,@Delimiter varchar(10) = ','    -- Delimiting value to split on.
   ,@num       int = null           -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
select rn
      ,item
from(select rn = row_number() over(order by(select null))
           ,item = ltrim(rtrim(n.i.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')))
     from(select x = cast('<x>'+replace(@str,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as s
        cross apply s.x.nodes('x') as n(i)
    ) as a
where rn = @num
    or @num is null
;
```

```
declare @html varchar(1000) =
'<p>text here <a href="example.com/abc.pdf">link</a>
 some other text <a href="example.com">home</a>
 <a href="www.example.com/abc123.pdf">link 2</a></p>
 <input type="text" name="self closed tag" />
 <b>some more text</b>
';


select left(s.item
           ,patindex('%.pdf%',s.item)+3
           ) as link
from dbo.fn_StringSplitXML(replace(replace(@html
                                          ,'>'
                                          ,''
                                          )
                                  ,'<'
                                  ,''
                                  )
                          ,'href="'
                          ,null
                          ) as s
where patindex('%.pdf%',s.item) > 0;
```

### Output

| link |
| --- |
| example.com/abc.pdf |
| www.example.com/abc123.pdf |